# Удаленное подключение mysql - PHP БД

Tags: mysql

Имеется комп и ноут в одной сети через роутер. Ноут по wi-fi, ПК - напрямую кабелем от роутера. Друг друга видят, все норм. На ноуте есть БД, данные которой постоянно меняются, поэтому нужно к ней подключаться с ПК. Через Navicat добавил нового пользователя user@192.168.0.86(ip клиента) со всеми правами(global previlegas). Теперь на ПК(клиенте) делаю запрос на подключение к БД с указанием хоста - Ip ноута в итоге получаю:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Попытка установить соединение была
>   безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен
>   нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за
>   неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.

PHP код:

```
define('DB_HOST','192.168.0.46');
define('DB_USER','user');
define('DB_NAME','db_name');
define('DB_PAS','password');
$dbh=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PAS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
```

Может кто подскажет, что еще дополнительно нужно сделать? Почему не конектится?

> вопрос решен с блокировкой брандмауэра и
>   настройками my.ini.

Comment: доступ точно к базе есть?  попробйте telnet 192.168.0.46 3306. 
3306 это порт по умолчанию для базы, если меняли то нужно тоже изменть.

Comment: вторая проблемка - нужен user@192.168.0.46 - куда коннектится, а не откуда.

Comment: сори за такой вопрос, но где прописывать telnet? Я прописываю в ком.строке и мне сообщает, что Telnet не является внутренней командой. Порты везде под MySql 3306. user@192.168.0.46 - я так понимаю здесь Ip - Это кто коннектится, а не куда(куда - ведь мы сейчас и находимся на сервере), согласно мануалу http://webew.ru/articles/414.webew

Comment: под управлением каких операционных систем работают ваши компьютеры? в конфигурации *mysqld* указано слушать все сетевые интерфейсы? не блокируются ли сетевые подключения брандмауэрами на ваших компьютерах?

Comment: alexander barakin, одна и та же ОС W7, а можно узнать детали по поводу просмотра конфигурации сетевых интерфейсов и блокировки сетевых подключений брандмауэром?

Comment: @Maxim, гугл говорить чтобы пользоваться телнетом на семерке нужно сначала его поставить. В консоли так  pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient" или панель уроавления => Включение или отключение компонентов Windows => кликнуть Клиент Telnet

p.s. ip он же DB_HOST это куда коннектинится. 
Телнетить нужно с клиента к серверу

Comment: @koks_rs, в ответ получил: не удалось открыть подключение к этому узлу, на порт 3306: сбой подключения, куда в таком случае дальше копать?

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: не забыли ли указать в mysql слушать не только 127.0.0.1 (bind-address = 0.0.0.0 в конфиге мускуля)? И рестарт.
[root@debian ~]$ less /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep bind
### new bind for access to mysql 
#bind-address  = 127.0.0.1
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Если сервер *MySQL* пингуется, то, скорее всего, закрыт порт файреволом/антивирусом